# jQuery $.get() method doesn't work under IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm having some trouble using jQuery AJAX on Internet Explorer. Here's the code snippet:

```
$('#upload-button').live('click', function() {
    // Get next upload server
    $.get('http://api.site.com/?sub=next_upload_server', function(resp) {
        // Set uploadify server setting
        resp = $.parseJSON(resp);

        $('#file-select').uploadify('settings', 'uploader', 'http://' + resp.server + '.site.com/upload.php');

        console.log($('#file-select').uploadify('settings','uploader'));

        // Start uploads
        $('#file-select').uploadify('upload', '*');
    });

    // Switch out the form for upload progress
    $('#upload-form').animate({opacity: 0}, function() {
        $('#progress-container').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

This code works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Under Internet Explorer though, it doesn't seem to work. If I put a `alert("test")` line right before the `$.get()` call, it will show it. If I put it in the function of the `$.get()` call, it won't. If I put it after the `$.get()` call (before I switch out the form for upload progress) it shows the alert.

Is there any reason this AJAX call wouldn't work in Internet Explorer? As far as I can tell it should. I've tested it in Internet Explorer 7 through 9. There are also no Javascript errors when I load the page or run this method.

Thank you.

**Edit:** After more debugging, if I go to `http://api.site.com/?sub=next_upload_server` directly in IE, it prompts me to download a file. When I open that file in Notepad, I see my expected AJAX response. Could that be something to do with it?

Comment: do you have a live page we can take a look at? :o

Comment: Unfortunately this is all localhost, but I have my future domain set up with virtual hosts and my hosts file so it acts as if it's live.

Comment: What does this get you?

    `$.get('http://api.site.com/?sub=next_upload_server', function(resp) {
         console.log(resp);
    });`

Comment: wait a second.. you are trying to do a cross domain get from localhost?

Comment: I have XAMPP set up on my machine and in the apache config I have virtual hosts for `site.com` and `api.site.com`, then in my hosts file I'm pointing both of those towards 127.0.0.1. It just makes it easier for me as it looks like they're on the internet but they're really on localhost. Helps me get my head around stuff.

Comment: try setting this header next: "content-disposition", "inline;filename=test.json"

Comment: @Terry, that call does nothing. If I put it in the `$(document).ready()` method it doesn't even get called according to the Network tab of IE's development tools.

Comment: @mkoryak, that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i assume you own/work for site.com and will eventually put your code there so it can work?

Comment: @Terry `$.getJSON` looks like it works. So it must be the AJAX call that's failing. And no mkoryak `site.com` is just an example, I'm not comfortable putting out my real URL because when the site is finally published the name could lead back to here.

Comment: @MartinHoe ok I wrote an answer then, cool.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in server script, try to send the following header:

```
header("content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Still not working, and I've verified that header is being send with the developer tools. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.getJSON()` or `$.ajax({ dataType: 'json' ... });`